# popup overlay in iframe not showing on top of page

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe, popup

I have an iframe on my aspx page. in this iframe I am calling another aspx page which contains an overlay and popup div. on a button click(in iframe) I am showing overlay and popup. I have set position absolute and z-index properly but problem is that popup and overlay only covering the iframe area not parent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can not put popup HTML in parent page I would suggest you to make clone of popup div and overlay div then append this to body of parent page. 
Make sure to copy event and data also if any.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the possible explanations of this behavior.

1. You might have defined the pop-up and overlay on the page you are calling inside the i-frame.
2. You might not have given the overlay width: 100%, height: 100%;
3. You should ideally use position: fixed for an overlay or else if your page scrolls down overlay will be out of view-port.

Can we see this page of yours somewhere ?

Comment: Yes I have defined the pop-up and overlay on tha page inside i-frame although I have given overlay width and height 100% and it is working properly on iframe. it is covering entire iframe area. but i want to show this overlay and popup outside the iframe(over main page)

Answer (score 0):

If you define the popup and overlay on the page containing the iframe (main page) instead, it should display as you want it to

Answer (score 0):

You cannot target parent page from a page inside iframe.. Its not possible.. The pop up will take iframe as its parent page... If you want popup to cover over the screen then the only way you can do that is by defining all the controls defined in the page which u call in iframe, inside a div in parent page itself.

Say: You have a.aspx page. Inside that you have an iframe with id=frame. Now the src of iframe u set it as b.aspx. So whatever controls you have in b.aspx, you can define a div inside a.aspx and put all the controls of b.aspx into that div.. So that now you can target a.aspx for your popup..

I dont know whether you have specific reason for defining an iframe and calling another page.. But if there is no specific reason then you can go with this method.. :)

**Let me know if you have any doubt**

Comment: I have strong reason to do this because the parent page is a cms page and this cms page also used for other url(s)(Page id) that's why I have used iframe. anyways thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You are welcome.. But I am sure that you cannot target main page from a page inside an iframe..

Comment: I can suggest you one more thing.. You can set a div only for the page where you want popup.. When that div is visible jus set iframe invisible and vice versa.. Will that be fine???

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for you.

1. Put you overlay in the parent page i.e. on the page that containes the iframe.

   ```
   function showHide(){

       parentWin = window.parent;

       var overlay = parentWin.document.getElementById('mask');

       if(overlay.style.display == 'none'){
           overlay.style.display = 'block';
       }

    }
   ```
2. Use the above function to access the overlay of parent page from the page which is inside the i-frame and you are good to go.

Let me know for any issues